# Could not attach to pid: "1839"

Tags: macos, react-native, xcode9

[image]

Hello there, I've got this issue in Xcode. I've googled it, but was unsuccessfully, nothing helps me. Can someone help, please?

Comment: Is it always the same pid?

Comment: Every time I close the Xcode + Emulator and open it again, it changes the pid.

Comment: Can you can check if it's a permissions issue by running Xcode as root?

Comment: How can I do this? I'm newbie with MacOS.
OBS: I have installed the Xcode manually.

Comment: Open a terminal and type `sudo /the/full/path/to/the/xcode/executable`. You can probably find that path with `which xcode`.

Comment: sudo: /Applications/Xcode.app: command not found. I received this

Comment: Then that isn't the path to the executable.

Comment: which xcode don't return nothing

Comment: It's possible the Xcode executable is not called `xcode`. You will need to find the path and name of the executable. Then you can `sudo` it.

Comment: How to access these files where macos install the apps?

Answer (score 0):

Cause:
You may be using the Distribution Certificate / Provisioning Profile, but trying to run the code into an iOS device through Xcode. This is the typical reason why this message shows up.

Solution:
Change to a Development Certificate / Provisioning Profile combination and run the code. This should install the app in the device and you should be seeing the output without issues

Answer (score 0):

You can try running this in the terminal.

```
sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable
```